# Silverlight Bing Maps Pushpin Styling

Tags: silverlight, xaml, controltemplate, bing-maps, pushpin

Does anyone know if the default control template and XAML style is available anywhere for the Bing Maps Silverlight controls?  We like the general appearance of the default Pushpin control, but want to have them available in multiple colors, not just the default orange.  It seems the only easy or straight-forward way to do this would be to provide a new ControlTemplate based off the default -- one for each color -- in our App.xaml.

Not a problem, except that I have been unable to identify the existing default control template.  Most of the core Silverlight toolkit controls have their default styles available on MSDN, but I haven't found the ones for the Bing Maps API.

Thanks,

Jeff

Comment: Could you just set the Background property to change color?

Comment: That's an interesting suggestion, Robert.  Haven't tried it, but we'll give it a shot and see if that works.  Will keep you posted, thanks.

Comment: @Robert: You should post that as an answer. Its correct it does work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just set the Background property to change color